# zsh-syntax-highlighting writes parameter expansion in black

Tags: command-line, zsh, syntax-highlighting, parameters, zsh-syntax-highlighting

I have installed [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting). This works well, except of one oddity: When I type a parameter expansion as a command argument, i.e.

```
foo $PWD
```

as soon as I type the `$P`, the parameter expansion is coloured black (which makes it invisible since I use a terminal with black backroung). It stays black when I type `$PW`, and turns visible (foreground colour, but underlined) once the `$PWD` is typed. It seems that the highlight attributes are "fg=black" for an "unfinished/unknown" parameter, but just unline for a known parameter.

I like the fact that they are coloured differently, since I can catch in this way typos in a variable name early. However, black is unreadable, since I also have a black background.

More interestingly, this happens only if the first word in the line is either an external command (like `foo` in my example), or a syntax keyword (`if`). It does not happen if the first word in the line is an internal command (such as `echo`), or an alias invocation, or a function call.

I searched the documentation, but did not find where this colouring of "unfinished parameter expansion" could be defined.

I'm using the following highlighters:

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main brackets pattern line)
```

I set various highlight categories, but there is none where I would simply set the foreground to black.

I do some highlighting of very specific parameters, which are important to me, like this:

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_PATTERNS+=('$(oncoll|onyt|oncp|ong)' 'fg=black,bold,bg=white')
```

But this also can't have any impact to the problem described here.

Does someone happen to know, which style setting affects me here?

Comment: According to this https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/1386f1213eb0b0589d73cd3cf7c56e6a972a9bfd/highlighters/main/main-highlighter.zsh#L62 the only default black is for `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[comment]`, which isn't what you describe, but try changing it, as I don't think you want it in black anyways. It could be also any with `none`, did you try changing the `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[default]` one to see if it affects it?

Comment: @Destroy666 : It's hard to believe, but it *was* the setting for `comment`. After I changed it to something better visible, it worked like a charm. If you post your finding as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the default styles for the `main` highlighter [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/1386f1213eb0b0589d73cd3cf7c56e6a972a9bfd/highlighters/main/main-highlighter.zsh#L31).

At this point of time, the only default styling with text (`fg`) configured to be black is [comment](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/1386f1213eb0b0589d73cd3cf7c56e6a972a9bfd/highlighters/main/main-highlighter.zsh#L62).

I don't know why exactly that `foo $PW` example counts as a comment, but the [documentation](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters/main.md) describes `comment` as:

> `comment` - comments, when `setopt INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` is in effect (`echo # foo`) 
> `comment` - elided parameters in command position (`$x ls` when `$x` is unset or empty)

The 2nd condition looks to be in effect as `$PW` is likely unset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really interesting, in particular, since undefined parameters in zsh are not really "elided" (when passed to a command, they take up a position in the argument list; they just turn into a null string).